# Error while deleting a file from SD card

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-camera

when i am deleting the file the code is running and showing me the toast of deleted file also but not **deleting** it from **SD card**.
**code** is below :

```
delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
             fn = baseAppDir.getPath()+ File.separator + folderName + File.separator
                     + folderName + "_" + Integer.toString(imgNo) + ".jpg";
            FileName = folderName + "_" + Integer.toString(imgNo)
                    + ".jpg";


            if (FileName!=null)
            {
                  deleteFile(FileName);
                Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                } else {
                Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Not Deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



        }});
```

Comment: Your toast is displayed because `FileName!=null`. No other reason. You should check the return value of `deleteFile()` before you display a toast.

Comment: `"Not Deleted"`. That should be `FileName==null`.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what's going on if you don't give us the error code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on following : [Delete a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html)

Your can do like as below :

```
try {
        deleteFile(FileName);
        Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
        System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
    } catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
        System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
    } catch (IOException x) {
        // File permission problems are caught here.
        System.err.println(x);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this may be its help full too..

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera");
    Log.e(TAG, " get path ..**... " + dir.getPath());
    Log.e(TAG, " get Directory ..**... " + dir.isDirectory());
    Log.e(TAG, " get Name  ..**... " + dir.getName());
    Log.e(TAG, " get strign  ..**... " + dir.list());
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        Log.e(TAG, " children .... ... " + children.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Delete old Image ...");
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

this is code for delete multiple image from `SD` card.

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
if (FileName!=null) {
     deleteFile(FileName);
     Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Not Deleted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

with

```
File file = new File(FileName);
if (file.delete()){
       Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
       Toast.makeText(ImageCaptureActivity.this, "Not Deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}